# Submit 0 If checkbox is checked else submit 1

Tags: php, drupal, salesforce

I have opposite condition. I have check-box and I want to submit value 1 if it is non-checked and values 0 if it is checked.

My first requirement is happening fine. I can print 1 If my check-box is non-checked but I am getting empty if my check-box is checked (Here I want to print 0) but I am getting empty:

My code:

```
function registerAtSalesforce($first_name,$communication){

    
        $data = [
            'userInput' => [
                'FirstName' => $first_name,
                'UserName' => $email,
        'MarketingCommunicationOptOut' => $communication ? false : true,
      ]
        ];
}
```

and function registerAtSalesforce where I am calling is below:

```
function uos_account_register_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

 
if(variable_get('sf_auth') === 1{
      registerAtSalesforce($form_state['values']['firstname'],$form_state['values']['ublox_communication'][1]); // This field "ublox_communication" of checkbox
          }
    }
```

I am using drupal 7.

Comment: In `$communication ? false : true`, shouldn't it be `$communication ? 0 : 1` if you want 1 and 0?

Comment: if(variable_get('sf_auth') === 1{    --- please close your if condition -->> if(variable_get('sf_auth') === 1) {

Comment: @Nigel Ren I can do that but I need to syn my field with salesforce field and salesforce field set as true and false

Comment: @Met Byrdy my condition is closed sorry I did not noticed during posting my question issue is not this.